# How can you transfer big files between Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10

Tags: linux, ssh

So I can transfer them via SFTP because windows has openSSH server pre-installed, but it's very slow. I want to transfer an 8GB+ machine so I can't do it via a USB neither because FAT32 can't handle. I need something fast.

Comment: There are commercial file transfer solutions which are much faster than any TCP-based tool, if you are willing to spend money on this.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of these?

Answer (score 1):

If they are they two different machines, try using rsync. Ubuntu will have it installed.
On Windows, you could install WSL and that usually has rsync installed as well.
If you dont want to install WSL, you could use cygwin on Windows, and install rsync on that

Comment: ***This is what I would do too*** but you don't need WSL (which I love) or cygwin (which I hate) to follow this suggestion.  I myself would simply use SAMBA with the Windows side doing the sharing and Linux as the client.  This is the easiest way to use SAMBA.  Once you have your SAMBA mount, you can use rsync as usual.  Even cp will work at this point.  I used to have to transfer HUGE builds between the OSs and this method was satisfactory for me.

Comment: Rsync may not be significantly faster for the simple case of transferring a large file. It can be helpful for resuming a partially complete transfer, or for updating a file which already exists at the destination.

Answer (score 1):

Format a USB Key as NTFS and move the data that way. That will work.

Alternatively, use a USB Drive (that will be formatted already as NTFS) and use that

I use both methods for large machines (some as large as 50 GB)